# Export date in a different format

Tags: 6, webforms, importing-exporting

I'm using the Webform module to gather contact, and support information on our webpage, but we've got a serious problem.

When I export the data using the download feature in the module, it exports the date as TEXT, which means I can't sort or filter in Excel. This is a HUGE problem, and it doesn't give me any sort of options to change how this should be exported.

To clarify, Webform is exporting a date such as "Jan 24 2013 - 14:53" which DOES NOT convert to date in Excel because Excel doesn't understand that date format. Excel requires something like "9/9/12" in order to convert to a date format.

How do I get Webform to export a date in a format that is understood from Excel?

I am using Drupal 6, if this makes any difference.